# Efficient PHP Checking Submitted Image Format

Tags: php, arrays, image, format

What is a more efficient way of checking an image's file type?

```
if (($_FILES["file_image"]["type"] != "image/jpg") &&
  ($_FILES["file_image"]["type"] != "image/jpeg") &&
  ($_FILES["file_image"]["type"] != "image/gif") &&
  ($_FILES["file_image"]["type"] != "image/png")) {
```

This is what I'm currently doing, but it seems like such a messy way to check. Arrays? I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is probably just as efficient as mine, but when it comes to stuff like this in PHP, it isn't going to make any difference at all - just write what's easier to read and understand.

```
if (!in_array($_FILES["file_image"]["type"],
    array('image/jpg','image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png')) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$x = array("image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png" , "image/gif", "image/bmp");
foreach ($x as $a)
{
    echo "$a ".preg_match("/^image\/(jpe?g|gif|png)$/", $a)."<br/>";
}
?>
```

look up preg_match  . If preg_match return 0 , it is not a match.
Use the regex  /^image/(jpe?g|gif|png)$/  .

Comment: why is this down voted ?  Many people have use regular expressions to solve this problem before.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but using a regular expression definitely isn't more efficient nor readable than his current code.